# Is language, made of the first half of the words from context-free language, context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

L is context-free language. Then we make new language L'={x|$\exists$y xy∈L,|x|=|y|}.
Is L' context-free or not always?
I'm stuck on this problem. I suppose that there are examples when L' isn't context-free, but can't create any.

Answer (score 6):

http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc/spr10/sol/solution4.pdf gives a counterexample:

$$L = \{ 0^i1^j2^j3^{3i}: i,j \ge 1 \}$$

is context free but half($L$) is not. The argument is sketched in the linked PDF.

Answer (score 2):

The proof in the PDF given is missing a lot of important details. Yes, it is a routine exercise to show that $L = \{0^n 1^n 2^n \mid n \geq 0\}$ cannot be pumped, but that doesn't mean a priori that a string $0^n 1^n 2^n$ can't be pumped as a string in the language $half(\{0^j 1^i 2^i 3^{3j}\})$ (If this were true for any language then $\Sigma^*$ for $|\Sigma| > 2$ wouldn't be context free!).

Instead, consider the CFL generated by $S \to 0S333 \mid 0T44333$ and $T \to 1T2 \mid 12$. This CFL is $0^j 1^i 2^i 44 3^{3j}$ and the intersection with the regular language $0^*1^*2^* 4$ is $\{0^n 1^n 2^n4  \mid n \geq 0\}$ which is evidently not context free.